# Confirm email field that not exists in database , not saving

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a registration form which has an input field for email confirmation.

```
<?= $this->Form->input('cemail',array('label'=>'Confirm E-mail')); ?>
```

In the UsersTable class inside validationDefault function i am trying to validate this field

```
        $validator
        ->email('cemail');
```

The form is not submitted though. Do i have to define this field anywhere else ?

Comment: Is it giving any error ?

Comment: No i dont see any error, but if i remove the line $validator
        ->email('cemail'); then the form is submitted successfully

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you intend to test the email for uniqueness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$validator
    ->requirePresence('cemail')
    ->add('cemail', 'validFormat', [
        'rule' => 'email',
        'message' => 'E-mail must be valid'
    ]);
```

and in controller

```
if ($Model->save($data)) {
   // data saved
}else{
   debug($Model->errors());
}
```

Comment: @user1292656 Please put all debug output in our question